# Is $\sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)$ continuous at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Here is the graph of $\sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)$:

[image]

According to the graph the right-hand side derivative is different from the left-hand side derivative at the point $x=0$. and a function is continuous at a point if the value of function at that point be equal to value of derivative of that function at that point here derivative doesn't exist at $x=0$.In the other hand the graph of function is like a continuous one. So is $\sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)$ continuous at $x=0$ ?

Comment: "and a function is continuous at a point if the value of function at that point be equal to value of derivative of that function at that point" -- What????????

Comment: @BrianMoehring Oh I messed this up! continuity is relevant to right-hand side and left-hand side limits not derivative . Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

Given that the graph is continuous, and the function is defined at zero, yes, this constitutes a "proof by graph". However, you may want to actually prove the statement as well. Thankfully in this case it is easy, since the limit operator goes through continuous functions.

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti It absolutely is incorrect. What is correct is that if it has a derivative THEN it is continuous also. But it is not necessary...

Answer (score 1):

You do not need graph and/or derivative: in point $x=0$ its arithmetical operations and compositions of continuous functions.